# Two tasks in one experiment design (self-paced-reading & grammaticality judgment)

Tags: psycholinguistics, language-acquisition, second-lang-acquisition, grammaticality

For experiment design experts, I want to know if it's possible to design an experiment on PsychoPy or Open Sesame in which the subject does a self paced reading (with measuring the reading times for each word), and then after they've read the last word, they judge the sentence whether grammatical or not (also need RT measured from the end of reading the sentence until responding to the grammaticality question).

I hope what I'm asking is clear. I'm not familiar with the two programs but I plan on learning (well, I played with PsychPy for a mini experiment!). I just want to know whether or not I'll be able to do such an experiment with either of these of these programs before going any further in my methodology.

Comment: I also want to know this, cause I'm thinking about designing a Self Paced reading task using PsychoPy

Comment: You do realize that "grammaticality judgement" is a trained response, right? Are you planning to train them?

Comment: @jlawler , Yes, I might add training items to the experiment if that's what you mean. I don't see how this makes a difference?

Comment: What I mean is that if your subjects are native English speakers educated in Anglophone schools, they probably have not learned how to form a grammaticality judgement. Anglophone schools do not teach grammar and most native English speakers do not know how to form a valid judgement about grammatical phenomena. Consequently if you want their "grammaticality judgements" to correlate in any way with professional judgements, you'll have to train subjects to some criterion. That's all.

Comment: Or you could just reformulate the question and say 'Does this sentence sound natural to you?', which would exclude their possible lack of grammar awareness and would just encourage them to listen to their inner feeling.